# Which ad signs can be destroyed?

Tags: achievements, x4-foundations

In the game there is an achievement to destroy 20 ad signs.

> **Adblock**
>
> Destroy 20 Ad Signs.

What exactly counts as such and how do I destroy it? I have tried the signs on stations and the high way, without success. They do not seem to take damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ones that project from a circular base up on the side of stations. you must target the circular base itself